# How to get the text from the HTML5 input field error message in Selenium?

Tags: html, validation, selenium, input, automated-tests

[image]

1. On giving invalid data in the email field it prompts for an HTML 5 alert message.
2. Firebug doesn't allow to inspect this error message (Please enter an email address) in two cases:

a. While inspecting with Firebug it is getting disappeared.

b. Right click on top of the error message doesn't work to inspect the element in DOM structure.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The Selenium API doesn't support directly a required field. However, you can easily get the state and the message with a piece of JavaScript (Java):

```java
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;

WebElement field = driver.findElement(By.name("email"));
Boolean is_valid = (Boolean)js.executeScript("return arguments[0].checkValidity();", field);
String message = (String)js.executeScript("return arguments[0].validationMessage;", field);
```

Note that it's also possible to use `getAttribute` to get the `validationMessage` even though it's a property:

```java
String message = driver.findElement(By.name("email")).getAttribute("validationMessage");
```

Answer (score 3):

In Python:

```
self.browser.get(self.live_server_url + registration_path)
email_input = self.browser.find_element_by_id('id_email_input')
validation_message = email_input.get_attribute("validationMessage");
```

http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement

Answer (score 0):

You get all html5 required field validation in this way.

```
String errorMessage = driver.findElement(By.id("email")).getAttribute("validationMessage");
```

Answer (score 0):

The *HTML5 input field error message* is actually the [*HTML5 Constraint validation*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55235180/7429447) message which is the outcome of ***Constraint API's*** [element.setCustomValidity()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/Constraint_validation#Controlling_the_text_of_constraints_violation) method.

To retrieve the text ***Please enter an email address.*** you can use either of the [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48376890/7429447):

- Using *Java* and *cssSelector*:

  ```
  WebElement emailField = driver.findElement(By.name("email"));
  System.out.println(emailField.getAttribute("validationMessage"));
  ```
- Using *Python* and *xpath*:

  ```
  emailField = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "email")
  print(emailField.get_attribute("validationMessage"))
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussion in:

- [How to validate html5 constraint validation message using Selenium-Webdriver and Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55352477/7429447)
- [How can I extract the text of HTML5 Constraint validation in https://www.phptravels.net/ website using Selenium and Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53591764/7429447)