# Selenium Webdriver - how to find css/xpath for 'inline warning message' that disappears after few seconds?

Tags: selenium

I was trying to capture or (find the css/xpath) the inline warning message that disappears after few seconds (BTW, I am using Selenium WebDriver / Java for my automation).

eg: In the below public link, I try to click Reset Button without entering any email. The text box briefly shows 'Please fill out this field." I want to automate if it is showing this message as expected.

https://app.shipt.com/password_resets/new

Please help.

PS: I tried to search this website and google but could not find any useful information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For actions that appear or disappear after certain time you should use Expected Conditions:

```java
 WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
 WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("someid")));
```

And then you can click on element as usual.

However in case of the shipit page you are trying to automate the popup is a native HTML5 popup, so you cannot use Selenium directly to get the message, and you have to use this workaround:

[Stackoverflow - how to get HTML5 error message in Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38812466/how-to-get-the-text-from-the-html5-input-field-error-message-in-selenium?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)