# How to handle dynamic text with no div tags and no info where they are coming from in Selenium?

Tags: selenium

I have registration form for which I am trying to create a script.If we don't enter any value in any of the fields and click submit, it is showing a dynamic error message that "Please fill out this field!"

[image]

There is no div tag for this text. Moreover, if we click anywhere on the screen, it is disappearing. Can anyone tell, how to read this text?

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the text from the HTML5 input field error message in selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38812466/how-to-get-the-text-from-the-html5-input-field-error-message-in-selenium)

Answer (score 0):

When the field is marked as required, the Browser shows the message when the form is submitted. There is no way available for you to access it.

You can handle it within your test code by checking that all required fields are entered before submit is called.