# Selenium tests fail with azure pipeline sometimes and pass locally

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, timeoutexception

Test cases fail while not finding a link or any validation messages after a button click.

I used explicit waits for page to load:

```
var waitForDocumentReady = new WebDriverWait(WebDriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
            waitForDocumentReady.Until((wdriver) => (WebDriver as IJavaScriptExecutor).ExecuteScript("return document.readyState").Equals("complete"));
```

For wait specific div of validation messages:

```
 WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(WebDriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
            wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.ClassName("validationErrors")));
```

But test cases pass sometimes with pipeline and fails sometimes.

Comment: How are you running your test cases in azure? Headless, or are you rendering a browser? I have seen issues with unexplained failures like this when running in non-headless mode.

Comment: @Gkm Did below answers help you fix this case, Could you share any updates?

Comment: @Christine, it is just the opposite for me. Most everything runs fine at AzDo when I set the WebDriver to headed mode and the release is checked "Test mix contains UI tests". But when I specify WebDriver Headless=true, then tests that follow the press of the [Save] button fail. There is something with processing of the button that I have yet to resolve. There are other stack overflow tests that go over this phenomenon.

Comment: @donvnielsen Your issue in headless mode may be related to some of the settings that are enabled - I have personally seen issues with headless mode where a browser size was not specified, resulting in a small default browser size which did not render the page correctly. Feel free to post your chrome options upon driver initialization if you would like some help troubleshooting those settings.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend following:

- When ever your tests fail take a snapshot at that moment.
  sometimes when you run your tests locally the network communication
  is a bit faster than running on server. Which means a spinner or a
  loading control may not appear locally because results were retrieved
  fast enough but the loader will appear when there is delay from
  server in sending the response to client.
- If you are trying to run your tests in FF headless on remote grid
  setup then it is not yet stable in my experience.
- Identify the pattern in failed scenarios which frequently fail and
  try and run them multiple times in a loop and identify the pattern of
  failure. In one of my case there was an actual bug in the performance
  of the application which used to get reproduced whenever the tests
  ran immediately in bulk

Answer (score 1):

I was having this issue, except my test would always fail in Azure Pipelines but pass locally. Not running in "headless" mode fixed my problem. To do this, make sure "Test mix contains UI tests" is checked in your "Visual Studio Test" task.[image: Check "Test mix contains UI tests"]

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things you need to take care as follows:

- *Test cases fail while not finding a link or any validation messages after a button click*: A lot depends on the attributes of the *button*. In case the *button* contains either of the following attributes/events the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes) would be getting updated and subsequently trying to find the desired element may **fail**:

  - [onclick()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp) event:

    ```
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
    ```
  - [jQuery click()](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_click.asp) Event:

    ```
    $("p").click(function(){
       alert("The paragraph was clicked.");
    });
    ```
  - So after a *button* click, to find the desired element you need to induce you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_WebDriverWait.htm) for the [`ElementExists()`](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions_ElementExists.htm).
  - You can find a relevant discussion in [ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible returns TimeoutException even when element is present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50853798/expectedconditions-elementisvisible-returns-timeoutexception-even-when-element-i/50855181#50855181)
- `ExecuteScript("return document.readyState").Equals("complete")`: This line of code is not that effective to ensure if the desired element(s) are **present**/**visible**/**interactable** with in the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp).

  - You can find a relevant discussion in [Do we have any generic function to check if page has completely loaded in Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50327132/do-we-have-any-generic-function-to-check-if-page-has-completely-loaded-in-seleni/50329056#50329056)
- However to *wait for specific div* with `ElementExists()` should have worked. The relevant HTML would have helped us to analyze what went wrong. However, if the *validationErrors* related element is based on  [HTML5 Constraint validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/Constraint_validation#Controlling_the_text_of_constraints_violation) then you have to use the [GetAttribute()](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_IWebElement_GetAttribute.htm) method.

  - You can find a relevant discussion in [How to handle html5 constraint validation pop-up using Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55223934/how-to-handle-html5-constraint-validation-pop-up-using-selenium/55235180#55235180)