# How to validate html5 constraint validation message using Selenium-Webdriver and Java

Tags: java, html, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait, constraint-validation-api

How do I validate the following message? The required class has the floating message.:

[image]

try the following, but I get the error "no such alert"

```
package firsttestngpackage;
import org.openqa.selenium.Alert;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class LoginBambu {

public String baseUrl = "http://132.148.19.159:8086/panel/#/login";
String driverPath = "H:\\chromedriver.exe";
public WebDriver driver;    

@Test
public void IniciarSesion() {
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", driverPath);
driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get(baseUrl);

WebElement login = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#page-top > div.margen-panel-60.ng-scope > div > div.row.container-fluid.ng-scope > div:nth-child(1) > div > form > button"));
  login.click();

  String mensaje=driver.switchTo().alert().getText();
  System.out.println(mensaje);    
}
}
```

Comment: It's not a JS alert. If I remember correctly, it's a browser(Chrome)-specific warning message that you can't detect using Selenium.

Answer (score 1):

The *HTML5 Constraint validation* message is the outcome of [Constraint API's element.setCustomValidity()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/Constraint_validation#Controlling_the_text_of_constraints_violation) method.

> **Note**: HTML5 Constraint validation doesn't remove the need for validation on the server side. Even though far fewer invalid form requests are to be expected, invalid ones can still be sent by non-compliant browsers (for instance, browsers without HTML5 and without JavaScript) or by bad guys trying to trick your web application. Therefore, like with HTML4, you need to also validate input constraints on the server side, in a way that is consistent with what is done on the client side.

### Solution

To retrieve the text which results out from the `element.setCustomValidity()` method, you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  import org.openqa.selenium.By;
  import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
  import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
  import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
  import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

  public class validationmessage {

      public static void main(String[] args) {

          System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
          ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
          options.addArguments("start-maximized");
          options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
          options.addArguments("--disable-extensions"); 
          WebDriver driver =  new ChromeDriver(options);
          driver.get("http://132.148.19.159:8086/panel/#/login");
          WebElement username = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input.form-control.ng-pristine.ng-invalid.ng-invalid-required.ng-touched[placeholder='Usuario']")));
          System.out.println(username.getAttribute("validationMessage"));
      }
  }
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Please fill out this field.
  ```