# How to extract the error hint of text box when user entered incorrect value in Selenium

Tags: java, html, selenium, validation, selenium-webdriver

When incorrect value is entered in textbox next hint is appeared:

[image]

HTML:

```
<form action="/login" method="post" class="form-horizontal"> <input type="hidden"> 
    <div class="form-group form-group-withLabel"> 
        <input type="email" name="_username" id="inputEmail" required="" autofocus="" autocomplete="off"> 
        <label for="inputEmail" class="inner-label">Email address</label> 
    </div> 
    <div class="form-group form-group-withLabel"> 
        <input type="password" name="_password" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password" required=""> 
        <label class="inner-label" for="inputPassword">Password</label> 
    </div> 
</form>
```

I need to get text from this hint.

I have tried to used:

```
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert()->getText();
```

but it did not help.

How to get text from such hints?

Comment: Can you share HTML code?

Comment: `<form action="/login" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
<input type="hidden">
<div class="form-group form-group-withLabel">
<input type="email" name="_username" id="inputEmail" required="" autofocus="" autocomplete="off">
<label for="inputEmail" class="inner-label">Email address</label>
</div>
<div class="form-group form-group-withLabel">
<input type="password" name="_password" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password" required="">
<label class="inner-label" for="inputPassword">Password</label>
</div>
</form>
`

Comment: When you hover to that error message, do you see any tooltip or any other tag?

Comment: No, this hint is not defined in html code

Comment: Feeze DOM in the moment of the textbox appears to see it is defined in the source code. See how to freeze DOM here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19422214/how-can-i-inspect-disappearing-element-in-a-browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error hint is basically the [*HTML5 Constraint validation*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55352477/7429447) message which is the outcome of [Constraint API's element.setCustomValidity()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/Constraint_validation#Controlling_the_text_of_constraints_violation) method.

To get text from the error hint you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the [*elementToBeClickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63301869/7429447) and you can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *cssSelector*:

  ```
  System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input#inputEmail[name='_username']"))).getAttribute("validationMessage"));
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@id='inputEmail' and @name='_username']"))).getAttribute("validationMessage"));
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [How can I extract the text of HTML5 Constraint validation in https://www.phptravels.net/ website using Selenium and Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53591764/7429447)

Comment: thanks for answering! it works for Java, but it is impossible to get validation message in php. I have used the same approach but no success

Comment: Feel free to raise a new question as per your new requirement.