# Which Web Automation tool can handle Bootstrap popover ? Unable to inspect Bootstrap popover element using dev tool

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, browser-automation, developer-tools

I am trying to automate a form and verify its validations.
Bootstrap popover is used as validation messages in a form. It appears and then disappears in a few seconds.
When i try to inspect this validation message shown in Bootstrap popover, it does not show anything. it does not eve highlight this element using Inspect highlighter.
Check image for Inspect element for same

[image]

Comment: This Helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38812466/how-to-get-the-text-from-the-html5-input-field-error-message-in-selenium