# How to find prompt by Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, alert

Does anybody know how to find this type of element by Selenium? (to validate its presence or text)?
[image]

I tried to catch it as alert (swithToAlert()) but it doesn't work. Any ideas? It is also can not be inspected as element and I can't find it in Elements. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Update the question with the text based relevant HTML of the element and your code trials.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38812466/how-to-get-the-text-from-the-html5-input-field-error-message-in-selenium

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This uses [HTML5 form validation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/validation/). This is created by the browser, and does **not** exist in the DOM. Therefore Selenium cannot *see* this.

You can access this using JavaScript. Here is a brief code sample:

```
JavascriptExecutor jsExecutor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
WebElement field = driver.findElement(By.tagName("input"));  // your input box

if (!(Boolean) jsExecutor.executeScript("return arguments[0].validity.valid;", field)) {
        return (String) jsExecutor.executeScript("return arguments[0].validationMessage;", field);
    }
```

The [entire API](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#the-constraint-validation-api) is documented.

> element.validity.valid

> Returns true if the element's value has no validity problems; false otherwise.

So this popup is displayed if this returns `false`, but only **after** clicking Submit on the form.

Comment: What does `return arguments[0].validity.valid;` does/returns?

Comment: It works! I can get text from this prompt message. There is one more question: how to check that this window is being displayed now?